# Using Flow with SharePoint 2013 on prem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, flow

I have a client that uses SharePoint 2013 on premises. They have some workflow work coming up to automate. I wanted to see if there is a way to use Microsoft flow with SharePoint 2013, is this possible to setup maybe by using some sort of a gateway? If someone has done this, please share the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the [onprem gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem) and you should have the global admin account to create flow and configure gateway.

- Access to download and install the On-Premises data gateway on a
  server.
- Access to a SharePoint 2013 or 2016 environment.
- Already have a subscription set up with PowerApps and Flow.

[SharePoint Gateway: PowerApps and Flow](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35244.sharepoint-gateway-powerapps-and-flow.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Data Management Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem) to connect Flow/PowerApps/PowerBI to on-prem resources.

Flow and PowerApps won't be able to access all data types in SharePoint pre-2019 on-prem, however. Test your specific scenario to see if it works.